# Want to pass JavaScript variable from one php template to another

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, variables, parameter-passing

I am having some problems with passing one JS variable to another. 
I am using HubSpot forms and their event onFormSubmit

```
redirectUrl: "/lp-thank-you-page/",
onFormSubmit: function($form) {
var email = document.getElementById("email-feca4800-6b73-4a38-8f80-1406a1b726b7").value;
}
```

Basically i want to use the variable email to another page template, which is the thank you page. On the thank you page i have to redirect the user to their specific email so my url parameters should look like this: 
**login?req=md-freetier-signup&src=*Email***
and i am using this:

```
<script>
setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);
function Redirect()
{
    window.location="https://myurl.com/login?req=md-freetier-signup&src="+email;
}
</script>
```

But i am pretty sure the value is not passing at all to that other template and i am not sure how to make it pass so my code works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem will be your scope. You create the email variable inside a function and then try to get it in another function that is outside the scope of your onFormSubmit function so in your Redirect function it will not recognize your email variable. try defining the email variable in your general scope and then filling it up in the onFormSubmit function. This way you can use it in other functions.

Comment: For the record, your issue is that the page the form is on is setting `var email = 'whatever' but it's being wiped when you redirect to the thank you page.

Then when you try to access it on the thank you page and go to the login page the email value isn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass the variable in the localstorage in JS :

```
localStorage.setItem('email', 'your@email.fr');
```

and then you can get it back

```
localStorage.getItem('email');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save this variable in a session in order to access it later. This will circumvent HubSpot and will allow you to retrieve these variables at any time.

Example:

```
redirectUrl: "/lp-thank-you-page/",
onFormSubmit: function($form) {
    var email = document.getElementById("email-feca4800-6b73-4a38-8f80-1406a1b726b7").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("email",email);
}
```

And on the other page:

```
setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);
function Redirect()
{
    var email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
    window.location="https://myurl.com/login?req=md-freetier-signup&src="+email;
}
```

If you never use the session variable after this again make sure to delete it with `sessionStorage.clear();`

Comment: Thank you. That actually worked perfectly, didn't really thought to use sessionStorage at first, but i believe that is the fastest way, with just adding 2 lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, it is a context problem. 
Replace `var email = document.getElementById("email-feca4800-6b73-4a38-8f80-1406a1b726b7").value;` by `window.email = document.getElementById("email-feca4800-6b73-4a38-8f80-1406a1b726b7").value;` and `window.location="https://myurl.com/login?req=md-freetier-signup&src="+window.email;` should work.

This is a working solution, not a good one though ! Prevent from using the "window" object as much as you can and always think namespace instead, when you can that is and I don't know how much HubSpot allows you to.

Comment: This shouldn't work because there's a redirect after form submission, which happens after email is set but before the redirect function the user created.